# Async Background thread WebServices

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

Im receiving an error which tells me at run time it cannot serialize.

an exception is catching the error at the line

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_UPDATE, envelope);

the error is: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: sprint.telematics.sprinttelematicstracking.RequestInfo@42df66d8

I am using WebServices and trying to run one on a background AsyncThread but keep receiving the error. The ASyncThread is an InnerClass of MainActivity

```
public class JobStatus extends AsyncTask<SoapObject,Object, SoapObject> 
{
    String sessionID;
    Globals globals;

    int jobStatus = 0, requestsSent = 0;
    Context context;
    CreateJobStatus createJobStatus;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    @Override
    protected SoapObject doInBackground(SoapObject... request) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(int i=10;i<100;i +=10)
        {
            try
            {
                    requestSent = requestSent + 1;

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request[0]);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;

                    try
                    {
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_UPDATE);

                        //this is the actual part that will call the web service
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_UPDATE, envelope);

                        //Get the SoapResult from the envelope body
                        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                        if(result != null)
                        {
                            jobStatus = jobStatus + 1;
                            TextView jobStatus_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JobsStatus);
                            jobStatus_.setText(jobs + " of " + requestsSent);
                        } 
                } 
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                publishProgress(i);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: because you are trying to access UI element from background thread and don't use Thread.sleep() method.\

Comment: should i get rid of Thread.sleep()?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
TextView jobStatus_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JobsStatus);
jobStatus_.setText(jobs + " of " + requestsSent);
```

from

> doInBackground

(You can't access UI elements from a background thread)
Instead, put these on your AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.

Comment: the error is coming from this line though         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_UPDATE, envelope);

Comment: Then please add the error you are getting to your question